# MAMP not showing all tables in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm working locally on a joomla project using MAMP. I need to access all my tables from phpmyadmin but it only shows me 68 tables out of the 150 table listed. I absolutely need to see all the 150 tables. Does anyone know what to do so phpmyadmin shows ALL tables? Is there a parameter that only allows it to show up to 68 tables? How can I change it?
Thanks

Comment: Are you using root when opening the application? If not, the username might not have permission to view those tables.

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version? Are you talking about not seeing the table names on the left side, or in the main panel?